# Using itoa() Function

Tags: c

When I compiled the code below, the compiler showed an undefined reference to itoa() function. But, when I searched; I found that itoa() is standard. Why is it so?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 int main()
{

  int i;
  char buffer [33];
  printf ("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  itoa (i,buffer,10);
  printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: No, there is no standard C `itoa` function. It's an extension in some library implementations.

Comment: why there is a restriction over some compilers?

Comment: It's not a "restriction", it is simply not part of the C standard, or any other published standard actually. The standard way to convert a string to an integer is [the `strtol` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Answer (score 0):

Please check link below.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

`itoa` is not standard function but some compiler support it.

On above link few alternative for it is provided.

Comment: I don't think a C++ link is useful for a C based question (Even if it does not matter for this specific question, someone might be tempted to use the link as a permanent source of information. Sooner or later, that might end up bad)

Comment: @tofro If you check carefully left side bar of page, its reference for `C library`